# Apache: redirecting an entire directory to the root of another site

Tags: redirects, apache

I want to redirect everything from a certain subdirectory to the root of another site, i.e. without the subdirectories:

- `example.com/jobs` should be redirected to `jobs.example.net`
- everything path behind `/jobs` should be omitted

  - Thus, `example.com/jobs/foo` should also be redirected to `jobs.example.net`

This last part is the most difficult as with `Redirect 301 /jobs jobs.example.net` the path `/foo` is not omitted. Thus, `example.com/jobs/foo` is redirected to `jobs.example.net/foo` which throws a `404 Not Found` error, as this page doesn't exist.

How can I achieve that the path is omitted in a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) `Redirect`, but with [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch). If you use a regular expression, but leave the `$1` s*ubstitution* for `(.*)` out of the *URL*, it will redirect to that exact URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/jobs(.*)" "http://jobs.example.net/"
```

Then, you will probably find many examples on how to do this with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but you should [avoid](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) using it when there is a mod_alias alternative, as above. For completeness, here's a mod_rewrite alternative:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/jobs" "http://jobs.example.net/" [R=301,L]
```

Both will redirect everything starting with `/job`, including `/joblessness`; not just the URLs `/job` and `/job/*`. If you wish to avoid that, you could put the rules inside a `<Directory /path/to/jobs>` section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried using `RedirectMatch` but I inserted an `$1` which had the same result as my `redirect` example in my original post. Regarding your remark, is this the good syntax to put it in a directory? 
`<Directory /path/to/jobs> 
RedirectMatch 301 "^/(.*)" "http://jobs.example.net" </Directory>`

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: I had to use `<location>` instead of `<directory>` as the path is not a real directory path but only a URL. The rest remains the same. Thanks for your good advise!